System.InvalidOperationException: 'Action being performed on this control is being called from the wrong thread. Marshal to the correct thread
So I have been calling a class method from my mainform with threading enabled there. But when I passed param to the obj method it showed this error, I could not fix it as there is no invoke method in treenode property
Called method with threading from the maiform
var PopulateTreeThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    response = treeViewObj.PopulateDirectories(rootNode, $"ftp://{hostIPAddress}:{port}",
    hostUserName, hostPassword,
    request, response);
    Thread.Sleep(25);
});
PopulateTreeThread.IsBackground = true;
PopulateTreeThread.Start();

your text
The method in the class is
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace FileManagerClient
{
    public class TreeView
    {
        public FtpWebResponse PopulateDirectories(TreeNode parentNode,
            string ftpRootPath,
            string hostUsername,
            string hostPassword,
            FtpWebRequest request,
            FtpWebResponse response
            )
        {
            try
            {
                // ftp request for each directory list
                request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpRootPath);
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(hostUsername, hostPassword);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                request.KeepAlive = true;

                response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                string directoryContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string[] directories = directoryContents.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                List<string> modifiedDirectories = new List<string>();

                foreach (string directory in directories)
                {
                    // splitting directory name for refined folder
                    string[] parts = directory.Split('/');

                    // getting last string after '/' as that will be present directory "AWGSS/DG" will give DG
                    string modifiedDirectory = parts[parts.Length - 1];

                    // refined directories name to remove confusion
                    modifiedDirectories.Add(modifiedDirectory);
                }

                // converting list to string array before passing
                string[] finalDirectories = modifiedDirectories.ToArray();

                foreach (string directory in finalDirectories)
                {
                    // creating node for each directory
                    Console.WriteLine($"directory looks like this: {directory}");

                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(directory);
                    parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);

                    Console.WriteLine($"new stream looks like this: {ftpRootPath}/{Path.GetFileName(directory)}");
                    // condition to differentiate between file and directory
                    bool isDirectory = Path.GetFileName(directory).Contains(".");

                    if (isDirectory)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // when directory found then run this method recursively
                        PopulateDirectories(node, $"{ftpRootPath}/{Path.GetFileName(directory)}", hostUsername, hostPassword, request, response);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception
                // MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
}

I was trying to do a successful multithreading which should not block the UI, but it still blocks UI and cannot do anything in the UI
I am expecting the method being running while I can work with the UI, so UI should not be blocked

It sounds like you already know you have to call Invoke when accessing the UI from a different thread. TreeNodes don't have an Invoke method since they're not really Controls, but they do have a reference to their TreeView, and that does have an Invoke method. So something like this then:
parentNode.TreeView.Invoke(() => {
   TreeNode node = new TreeNode(directory);
   parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
});

If you need to cast to Action for some reason it might look like this:
parentNode.TreeView.Invoke((Action)(() => {
   TreeNode node = new TreeNode(directory);
   parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
}));

But I don't know why you'd be getting that error.
Note that you also have the option of building the new TreeNode inside or outside of the lambda; these may also work:
TreeNode node = new TreeNode(directory);
parentNode.TreeView.Invoke(() => {
   parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
});

// or

TreeNode node = new TreeNode(directory);
parentNode.TreeView.Invoke((Action)(() => {
   parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
}));


But it is giving me an error for the lamda expression like this:
Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

@P0tat0627 hmm, which framework are you using? possibly you have to cast it to an Action or something but I don't see why you'd have to do that. I am able to compile it this way in .NET 6.

I am using .NET framework 4.8 for winforms application
